# Difference between sizeof(name) and sizeof name

Tags: c

I am following the C primer plus and encounter the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //provide strlen() prototype
#define PRAISE "You are an extraordinary being with a big big brain."
int main(void)
{
    char name[40];

    printf("What's your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);
    printf("Your name of %zd letters occupies %zd memory cells.\n", strlen(name), sizeof name);
    printf("Size of the name %zd", sizeof(name));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and run it:

```
$ ./a.out
What's your name? Trump
You are an extraordinary being with a big big brain."
Your name of 5 letters occupies 40 memory cells.
Size of the name 40
```

What puzzled me is that `sizeof(name)` is identical to `sizeof name`?

sizeof() is a library routine, but how abut sizeof, it seems as predicate and parameter as it was in command line.

Comment: So rude. My name is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and I get a segfault from your program :(

Comment: adding to what @Jabberwocky said, parenthesis **are** needed when evaluating the size of a type, for example `sizeof (char)`

Comment: I like to think of it as the parenthesis "belonging" to the type (pretty much like a cast). Some people overdo the parenthesis thing though (`sizeof (a)`, `return (42);`, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `sizeof` isn't a library function, it's a [special operator keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

It has two forms: One is with parentheses to get the size of a type. The other is not using parentheses and is for getting the size of the result of a generic expression.

With `sizeof(name)` you're really using the second variant, with the expression `(name)`. I.e. the parentheses are part of the expression and not the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 3):

The `sizeof` **operator** (not function) yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

It can be used *with or without parentheses* if the operand is an expression.
It can only be used *with parentheses* if it is a type.

So in your case, `sizeof(name)` and `sizeof name` are both valid.
But something like `sizeof char` would be invalid, whereas `sizeof(char)` would be valid.